# http://com.google how do they transform everything to RTL

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how everything on http://com.google is reversed. Not only images, but static text is reversed too. They use normal font and I couldn't find any transformation css. Can anyone explain how they changed direction of everything?

[image]

Nothing unusual there...

Comment: my best guess is that there is some javascript behind this magic ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Or to be more specific:

```
body {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); 
}

body {
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1); 
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```